# How to make a form to submit itself

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form with a `<select>` on the page. when the user selects an option, I want the form to submit itself. How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: @romainberger - If one of the answers is *perfect* then please select it as the correct answer (using the checkmark under the vote buttons)

Comment: It was telling me it was too early. I just did!

Comment: @romainberger - Good, I just saw that it looked like it was late enough, and that your account only has 18 rep, and most new users don't know to select a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe for the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event on the dropdown and invoke the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method of the containing form:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <select id="myDropdown">
        <option value="1">item 1</option>
        <option value="2">item 2</option>
        ...
    </select>

    ...
</form>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myDropdown').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="foo">
    <select onchange="document.foo.submit();"></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('select').change(function(){$('form').submit();});`

Needless to sayyou should be doing some more checking etc in there...